# SQL в PHP без использования PDO и т.д.

Tags: mysql, cmd, php, sql

Можно ли в PHP выполнить запрос к MySQL без использования средств, поставляемых расширениями (т.е. без использования PDO/MySQL/MySQLi и т.д.), например, через exec()? Если можно, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы и нет:

```
mysql -uroot -p%password% -e "use test; SELECT * FROM test_table;"
```

Вообще, никакой магии в исползовании баз данных нет. Я руками это до сих пор не трогал, но в принципе все запросы чуть ли не в исходном виде отправляются по сетке (или аналогу - unix-socket'у) серверу, который разбирает их и так же отправляет сериализованный ответ. То есть, грубо говоря, можно написать свой собственный драйвер, используя `fsockopen()` и некоторое количество свободного времени. Официальные расширения просто гарантируют а) своевременное и корректное устранение багов б) быстроту, т.к. написаны на сишке, которая в силу некоторых причин заведомо быстрее пыхи.

Comment: Спасибо, я был на верном пути.
Вместо use test можно использовать ключ -D test.